# Representing a series of numbers as an xml tree

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm, recursion

I have some numbers say 110,111,114,115,120,121,112,122,130,131
now I need to list them in an xml tree as

```
 - 110
 - 111  
    -114
    -115
      -120
      -121
      -122
 - -112
   -130
   -131
```

That is if a number x[i+1] is x[i] +1 then both are added as children of same tree. else
x[i+1] is added to a child tree to x[i]

I know it has to be done recursively, but I am such a dumb that I not able to get it right? In desperate need of help.

Comment: but according to your pattern, shouldn't the 130 and 131 nodes be the child of 112??

Answer (score 0):

It actually works as you describe, but that description is more linear than recursive:

> if a number x[i+1] is x[i] +1 then both are added as children of same tree. else x[i+1] is added to a child tree to x[i]

So this is just a loop initializing the previous node to the root element of the xml document. For the number sequence provided

```
110,111,114,115,120,121,112,122,130,131
```

it then generates the following XML ([PHP Example](http://eval.in/private/061589aeb10385)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <node value="110"/>
  <node value="111">
    <node value="114"/>
    <node value="115">
      <node value="120"/>
      <node value="121">
        <node value="112">
          <node value="122">
            <node value="130"/>
            <node value="131"/>
          </node>
        </node>
      </node>
    </node>
  </node>
</root>
```

So before writing code I think you first of all need to specify more properly which logic you actually want to follow. Unless it is not distinct you can not decide whether or not you want to solve it with recursion, xpath expressions and what not.

Answer (score 0):

> That is if a number x[i+1] is x[i] +1 then both are added as children of same tree. else x[i+1] is added to a child tree to x[i]

According to this description you do go not up to the high levels of the tree. So your tree should look like the following:

```
- 110
 - 111  
    -114
    -115
      -120
      -121
      -122
        -112
          -130
          -131
```

Just keep track of the last parent, and if x[i+1] <> x[i] +1, reassign the parent to the last node. And then add new node to the saved parent

Comment: wrong, he needs 112 to be the direct sibling of 111 as it satisfies x[i+1] = x[i]+1 for these two.

Comment: No, because 112 doesn't go right after 111 in the array which is called x, I guess.

Comment: that's why he needs a recursive solution. no matter wat the order of occurance in the array; so that means, currentNode should always be greater than previous node, if not than iterate backwards and find out the last previous node to which it is greater.

Comment: How do you know that the order doesn't matter? I do not see it from the description

Comment: then it won't be a much of a challenge :D,besides that's what the tree in the question shows

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, then we do not have the clear problem. How do you know to which parent to add the other node? You can add it to any and then you do not need any recursion. And clearly there is nothing about "currentNode should always be greater than previous node" in the problem description. So if you have other problem in your mind, post it in the separate question :)

Answer (score 0):

You need some stack;

```
stack<int> nodeHierarchy;
```

Then algorithm is simple: check if element if higher than previous. If so it would be eihther its sibiling or child.

Otherwise you need to go back through stack and do it again.

If element would be sibling, you need to go again back through stack.

Lets assume that root is 0 and all others elements are higher than 0.

```
nodeHierarchy.push(0); //root
foreach(int element){
    while(nodeHierarchy.top() + 1 >= element)nodeHierarchy.pop();
    //put element as next nodeHierarchy.top() child
    nodeHierarchy.push(element);
}
```

I believe, that is what you thought, but you described it wrong. If I'm wrong, others two answers should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED (ordered) RESULT XML:

```
  <root>
     <node value="110" />
     <node value="111">
         <node value="114" />
         <node value="115">
             <node value="120" />
             <node value="121" />
         </node>
     </node>
     <node value="112">
         <node value="122">
            <node value="130" />
            <node value="131" />
         </node>
     </node>
   </root>
```

I used to consider the order in this code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
int[] numArray = new int[] { 110, 111, 114, 115, 120, 121, 112, 122, 130, 131 };
XmlElement head = doc.CreateElement("root");      
doc.AppendChild(head);

XmlElement cur = doc.CreateElement("node");
cur.SetAttribute("value", numArray[0].ToString());
head.AppendChild(cur);
int pos = 0;
BuildXml(numArray, ref pos, ref doc, head, cur);
```

And recursive function

```
public static void BuildXml(int[] numArray, ref int pos, ref XmlDocument doc, XmlElement parNode, XmlElement curNode)
{
    if (pos < numArray.Length-1)
    {
        if (numArray[pos] + 1 == numArray[pos + 1])
        {
            XmlElement current = doc.CreateElement("node");
            current.SetAttribute("value", numArray[pos + 1].ToString());
            parNode.AppendChild(current);
            pos++;
            BuildXml(numArray, ref pos, ref doc, parNode, current);
        }
        else if (numArray[pos] < numArray[pos + 1])
        {
            XmlElement current = doc.CreateElement("node");
            current.SetAttribute("value", numArray[pos + 1].ToString());
            curNode.AppendChild(current);
            pos++;
            BuildXml(numArray, ref pos, ref doc, curNode, current);
        }
        else
        {
            XmlElement elem = null;
            foreach (XmlElement nodes in doc.FirstChild.ChildNodes) GetNode(nodes, numArray[pos + 1], ref elem);                
            XmlElement current = doc.CreateElement("node");
            current.SetAttribute("value", numArray[pos + 1].ToString());
            ((XmlElement)elem.ParentNode).AppendChild(current);
            pos++;
            BuildXml(numArray, ref pos, ref doc, ((XmlElement)elem.ParentNode), current);
        }         
    }
}

public static void GetNode(XmlElement elem, int val, ref XmlElement found)
{
    if (int.Parse(elem.GetAttribute("value")) < val)
        if (found == null || int.Parse(found.GetAttribute("value")) < val) found = elem;
    foreach (XmlElement childElem in elem.ChildNodes) GetNode(childElem, val, ref found);
}
```